# Replace only characters after symbol and before another?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, regex

I'm having real difficulty with this. Apologies for the noobish question.

Lines grepped out yields this:

```
192.168.1.234/50112(LOCAL\username)
```

Desired output:

```
192.168.1.234-(LOCAL\username)
```

I know I can make a statement that looks for "all characters after `/`" for the first part, since this forward slash is the first instance of a forward slash in each line.

How I do replace the number between `/` and `(` with `-` in each line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is always digits, you can say

```
$ echo "$line" | sed 's,/[[:digit:]]\+,-,'
192.168.1.234-(LOCAL\username)
```

Otherwise, if you don't know what's in there, match the slash and one or more non-parenthesis characters

```
$ echo "$line" | sed 's,/[^(]\+,-,'
192.168.1.234-(LOCAL\username)
```

You can actually do this right in bash with extended globbing:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo "${line/\/+([0-9])/-}"
192.168.1.234-(LOCAL\username)
```